# Iinfyom $header is undefined en la vista de app.blade.php

Tags: laravel

He instalado el plugin de Infyom para hacer unas pruebas, pero siguiendo todos los pasos y generando un crud a partir de una tabla que tengo creada me salta este fallo:

```
    ErrorException
Undefined variable: header (View: /var/www/testapp/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado buscando que podría ser el fallo, pero no he encontrado nada alguien sabe porque?
(tengo el menu.blade.php, la base de datos esta echa de forma correcta, estoy logeado pero falla)

Comment: El código va como texto por favor

Answer (score 0):

Ve a la funcion del controlador de esa vista **app.blade.php**,
puedes buscar en web.php y buscar alli el path de la ruta en donde te tira ese error para guiarte en que funcion y controlador esta mostrandose ese blade.

PD: prueba quitando, solo para verificar que si sea ese, aunque el error de por si especifica que no esta definida esa variable.

```
{{$header}}
```

Comment: Si lo he quitado y si va, pero al poner lo va... En el controlador generado por infyom, va hacia una vista y falla

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código de esa función?  el error te salta directamente cuando te logueas en el home, o ya estas en la ruta del crud?

Comment: falla al ir a la rota que ha creado el crud de infyom